# Filter categories in which (in another column) values differ

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, t-sql, dplyr

My table looks as follows:

Excel columns

```
B|C|D
Category    | Value |No diff values within category?
        A   123 TRUE
        A   123 TRUE
        A   122 FALSE
        B   121 TRUE
        B   121 TRUE
        B   121 TRUE
        C   10  TRUE
        C   10  TRUE
        C   10  TRUE
        C   11  FALSE
        D   23  TRUE
        D   23  TRUE
        D   23  TRUE
        D   23  TRUE
        D   22  FALSE
        D   23  FALSE
```

We are in excel for now and in the third column I have **=OR(B3<>B2;C3=C2)**
I check if the category of the previous row is different or the value in the previous row is equal to the current row.

If TRUE, it means there is no difference. If FALSE - there is a difference detected within the same category.

Then I filter out the FALSE values in third col.  to have categories in which there are differing values. (I may also filter out or delete duplicates).

QUESTION:

1. How can it be accomplished in R? Dplyr syntax? I am wondering how the Dplyr can refer to previous row and check a condition.
2. How can it be accomplished using a query language SQL?

   Thanks my friends for all answers!

Comment: You could use an analytic function in SQL, but you would need a fourth column specifying an order to the rows.  Have you tried anything yet in either R or SQL?

Comment: So as for R, you can have a look at `lag` function

Comment: @EricLecoutre `LAG` should also work with Oracle, SQL Server, or Postgres.

Comment: I am reading right now about lag() function in dplyr mutate... It is my first steps with dplyr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `R`, one approach is with `dplyr` as this is a group by do something problem.   We use `diff` after grouping by 'Category'.  The `diff` gets the difference of adjacent elements in 'Value', convert to a logical vector by checking if the output is 0 and concatenate with `TRUE` as the output of `diff` will be of length one less than the length of the original vector.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(Category) %>%
     mutate(Diff1 = c(TRUE, diff(Value)==0))
#   Category Value Diff1
#      <chr> <int> <lgl>
#1         A   123  TRUE
#2         A   123  TRUE
#3         A   122 FALSE
#4         B   121  TRUE
#5         B   121  TRUE
#6         B   121  TRUE
#7         C    10  TRUE
#8         C    10  TRUE
#9         C    10  TRUE
#10        C    11 FALSE
#11        D    23  TRUE
#12        D    23  TRUE
#13        D    23  TRUE
#14        D    23  TRUE
#15        D    22 FALSE
#16        D    23 FALSE
```

---

Another option in `R` is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Diff1 := c(TRUE, diff(Value)==0)), by = Category]
```

---

Or with `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$Diff1 <- with(df1, ave(Value, Category, FUN = function(x) c(TRUE, diff(x)==0)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Category = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
 "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), Value = c(123L, 
123L, 122L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 22L, 23L)), .Names = c("Category", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 
 -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query in SQL Server

```
    ;WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) ID,Category,Value from Table)
    select a.Category,a.Value,case when (a.Category=b.Category) or  (a.Value=b.Value) then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end [T/F]
    from CTE a inner join CTE b on a.id=b.id-1
```

Thanks